# API Management not showing functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management, .net-5

I have a function app (.NET 5) with two functions

[image: Function app overview]

I want to import these into the API Management service but when I choose the import function app option it displays no functions

[image: No functions]

I have followed the Microsoft [Guide for running functions on .NET 5.0 in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) set both functions to `AuthorizationLevel.Function`. Only different is the function is `public async Task<HttpResponseData>` instead of `public static HttpResponseData` as I have asyncronous dependencies I need to inject in.

```
        [Function("TransformAll")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestData requestData,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            ...
        }
```

I have restarted the function app (which used to solve this probalem in the past) but not this time.

Is there any additional configuration I need to add. Maybe give the Api Management service permissions?

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, I met same problem with yours. I also can't see the function list when I want to add them to APIM.

I don't think we can do it by any additional configuration. It seems azure function for .NET 5 doesn't support APIM now because I test to add function to APIM with another way(click "**API Management**" tab in my function app) and can't see the function list too.

[image]

[image]

And we can also see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages) shows .NET 5.0 for azure function is in "**Preview**" state.

[image]

So I think we can just add a blank api in APIM and input the function url as "Web service URL" to add the function to APIM.

[image]